# Celerybeat issues crontab'ed task on invalid date after USE_TZ value changed

Tags: django, celery, cron, celerybeat

A celery task defined to be run once a month using celerybeat

```
run_every = crontab(minute=0, hour=5, day_of_month=1)
```

is run immediately (on the 17th) when we switched from

```
USE_TZ = False
```

to

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Does anyone know a reason for this behaviour?
How can we prevent that in the future?

Thanks

Comment: This is very weird, since it shouldn't be related. Are you sure the date is set properly?

Comment: Yep. All machines are synching time from a local NTP server.